# How to compute the projection of a vector onto a n-dimensional box (hyperparallelepiped)

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, projection

**Definition**:

Let $C$ be a closed convex set in $\mathcal E$. For every $z\in \mathcal E$, there exists a unique minimizer (denoted as $\operatorname{Proj}_{C} (z)$ and called as the projection of $z$ onto $C$) of
$$
\min \{\frac{1}{2} \| x-z \|^2 | x\in C\}
$$
where $\| \cdot \|$ is the Euclidean norm.

Set $x^\star = \operatorname{Proj}_{C} (z)$ is the projection of $z$ onto $C$ if and only if
$$
\langle z-x^\star, x-x^\star \rangle \leq 0, \forall x \in C.
$$

**Problem**:

Given a hyperparallelipiped (box) set $[a,b]$ with $b>a$ and $a,b\in \mathbb R^n$, for any $z\in \mathbb R^n$, the projection of $z$ onto the box $[a,b]$ is $\operatorname{Proj}_{[a, b]} (z)$.

I wonder how to calculate $\operatorname{Proj}_{[a, b]} (z)$. Please teach me the details of the calculation process.

Comment: What you mean by $b>a$ if $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^n$? Are $a$ and $b$ reals and the set $[a,b]^n$?

Comment: A projection onto a cube is very easy. First, if $z\in C$ then $z$ is simply the minimizer. If $z\notin C$ then try to think what will minimize the distance from $z$ to the cube. Hint: clearly it will be on the boundary of the cube. You can plot a 2-D example on a piece of paper, then use the observation you get to formulate a proof on a general n-dimension

Comment: Is $\mathcal E$ the $n$-dimensional Euclidean space (i.e., with quadratic norm) ? Besides, could you answer to @ECL ?

Comment: @ECL For $b>a$, it means all elements in $b$ is greater than the corresponding elements in $a$, So it's element-wise greater operator, and both $a$ and $b$ are vector in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @iarbel84 Thank you for your suggestion. Actually, I know the results of the projection. But it is hard to me to prove it in mathematical derivation.

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes. $\mathcal E$ is the n-dimensional Euclidean space.

Comment: Three remarks : 1) Taking the sup norm (instead of the Euclidean norm) would probably ease the minimizing formulation. 2) You say you know the result of the projection on the hypercube : could you give it ? 3) "hyperparallelepiped" would be a more exact term than "hypercube".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique to solve this is by recalling that box constraints are separable. Over $\mathbb{R}^n$, we have $n$ variables $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$, where both the objective function and constraints are not dependent of each other. Therefore we will solve the projection problem in $\mathbb{R}$, and this will give the solution in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Consider the problem: $$\text{prox}(x) = \text{argmin}_{l\leq z\leq u} \frac{1}{2}(x-z)^2$$
Clearly if $l\leq x\leq u$ then $z=x$. Now assume $x<l$ or that $x>u$. It's easy to see that an optimal solution is attained on the boundary of the constraint set - we're talking about a line interval here, so the solution is very intuitive. To summarize: $$\text{prox}_{I_{[l,u]}}(x)=\begin{cases} &x, &l\leq x \leq u \\
& l, & x<l \\ & u, & x>u
\end{cases}$$
Which means that when $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and the feasible set $C=\{\mathbf{x}\,|\,l_i\leq x_i\leq u_i,\,i=1,\dots,n\}$ we have $$\text{prox}_{C}(\mathbf{x})=\begin{cases} &x_i, &l_i\leq x_i \leq u_i \\
& l_i, & x_i<l_i \\ & u_i, & x_i>u_i
\end{cases}$$
I will leave to you the proof as to why we can look at each coordinate independently of other coordinates, but it is really very simple. Recall that if we minimize a function comprised of separable functions, we just need to minimize each component on its own.